# ggplot change facet label using another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use the names of a different variable as my facet labels in ggplot. However, this variable has subscripts and spaces, the latter I think are resulting in errors when I try to use this variable as a label.  How do I fix this?  Changing the variable names in grps is not an option.

```
grpOrder <- c("B", "AB", "A")
data.frame(y    = sample(0:20, 30, replace = TRUE),
           x    = sample(0:20, 30, replace = TRUE),
           grps = fct_relevel(rep(c("A", "B", "AB"), each = 10), grpOrder),
           labs = rep(c("Aaaaaa[1]", "Bbbb[3]", "Ababa Bbbaaa"), each = 10)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~grps, labeller = label_parsed(labels = labs))
Error in parse(text = as.character(values)) : 
  <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: {
   ^
```

I've tried putting '~' as spaces, but that didn't help:

```
data.frame(y    = sample(0:20, 30, replace = TRUE),
           x    = sample(0:20, 30, replace = TRUE),
           grps = fct_relevel(rep(c("A", "B", "AB"), each = 10), grpOrder),
           labs = rep(c("Aaaaaa[1]", "Bbbb[3]", "Ababa~Bbbaaa"), each = 10)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~grps, labeller = label_parsed(labels = labs))
Error in parse(text = as.character(values)) : 
  <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: {
   ^
```

I have to use grps as the faceting variable because the facets are in a very specific order.  There are a LOT of facets in my actual dataset, so recoding everything manually is not an option.

Comment: Why not just use the `labs` variable for faceting: `facet_wrap(~labs)`?

Comment: @Peter I need to keep the facets in the same order as the grps variable.

Comment: You could achieve this by making the `labs` an ordered factor, using levels to organise the  elements in the order you desire.

Comment: Yes, but in my original dataset, I can put grps into the correct order with fct_relevel quite easily by passing in a vector that has the correct order.  I would have to write out all the names manually for labs which is a pain (there are a lot more than 3 facets!).  I'd rather have a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't quite have the syntax right here. The error message you are getting is because `labels_parsed` doesn't have access to the data frame you have piped in and doesn't use data masking, so it is trying to parse the *function* `labs`, not the *column* `labs`.

Since you already have a `labs` column, simply facet by that and pass `labels_parsed` as a function rather than a call.

If you need the labels to be in the same order as the groups, you can do this in advance:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(y    = sample(0:20, 30, replace = TRUE),
           x    = sample(0:20, 30, replace = TRUE),
           grps = fct_relevel(rep(c("A", "B", "AB"), each = 10), 
                              c("B", "AB", "A")),
           labs = rep(c("Aaaaaa[1]", "Bbbb[3]", "Ababa~Bbbaaa"), each = 10))
  
df$labs <- factor(df$labs, 
                  as.character(unique(df$labs))[unique(as.numeric(df$grps))])

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~labs, labeller = label_parsed)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks. I did consider this, but it re-orders the facets and I need them in the same order as grps.

Comment: @tnt so why not reorder them in the same way you reordered `grps`?

Comment: I would very much appreciate feedback on the downvote, from whoever thinks the answer is bad enough to deserve one.

Comment: I'm recordering grps with an existing vector that has the variable names in order already: fct_reorder(grps, vector).  Unfortunately, this doesn't work for labs because the variable names have changed.

Comment: I've updated the question to make this step more explicit.

Comment: @tnt You can copy the ordering over from `grps` indirectly - see my update